# App to Access Google Analytics

Tags: google-app-engine, google-analytics

I am a bit lost on whether it is possible to create an App with Google that will be able to access Google Analytics data of a GA user who permits the app access. Note that I am not looking to access my own data, but data for a number of clients who want to utilize the app to download their Google Analytics reports. Here is what I am looking to accomplish as an end results:

1. User logs into website
2. User is asked to approve app access to GA data with a form/button
3. User approves the access (or gives the app a Token, not sure about the workflow)
4. The app queries Google Analytics data on user's behalf and shows him the report

Can this be done and how? Could one create a google app, go through the App Review process and then have a working solution to for multitude of clients/customers who can use my app to download the reports?

Comment: What have you tried? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-js

Comment: Matt, this does not address my question. Obviously I have gone through most of the mainstream links out there. I was not looking for a long manual on API but rather a specific answer on App related interaction with Google API

Comment: The answer to your question is Yes it is possible to build an application which accesses the end users Google Analytics data. The link I sent you gives you all the steps necessary to create the most simple web application.  the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) is an open source example of one such application. All of google's APIs use [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) in which the end user can authorize your application to access their data.